# Why my navigation buttons in jqGrid are shown like this? Can I change its design? (Image present in question)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

[image]

Can I change the design of my jqGrid button? my `loadonce:false`, but in that case I can't use my pager because it gets disabled.

Comment: It seems, that you do not provide a correct information in the response for the paging. Since you use very old version you can look at this [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data) - how should your json response look like.

Comment: Thanks for your help! If possible for you could you please see my current issue and let me know where i am getting wrong." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68737228/why-my-jqgrid-shrinks-every-time-when-i-call-show " Really sorry for bringing it up like this