# Why my JqGrid shrinks every time when I call 'show()'?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jqgrid

I am trying to show a JqGrid on page every time I choose **OPTION** from the dropdown menu which consist of total three options(**OPTION**,**TEXTUAL** and **VALUE**). I am using `show` and `hide` so that I can hold the value entered by the user at least for the time he is on that page. When the page loads with **OPTION** already selected on the dropdown menu then the table is showing and working fine, even after switching to other options which results in hiding of table and then making it back to **OPTION**, still it is working fine.
The issue comes when I the page loads with selected option **TEXTUAL** or **VALUE**. When I change the option to **OPTION** it shrinks my jqGrid. And when I move chrome browser by selecting it from Toolbar, then it automatically fixes it.

```
<div class="row table-responsive">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="jqGrid" style="display:block">
     <table id="OptionTable"></table>
     <div id="divOptionTable"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Script to hide and show jqGrid

```
if($("#dropdownmenu").val()=="Option")
          {             
             $(".jqGrid").show();
          }
    else
          {
             $(".jqGrid").hide();
          }
        });
```

MY JQGrid code:

```
$("#OptionTable").jqGrid({
                mtype: "GET", 
                url: "---url---",
                datatype: "json",
                async: false,
                colNames: [
                   "col0", "col1", "col2"
                ],
                colModel: [
                    { key: true, name: "col0", index: "col0", editable: false, hidden: true },
                    { key: false, name: "col1", index: "col1", editable: false, hidden: false },
                    { key: false, name: "col2", index: "col1", editable: false, hidden: true }
                ],
                pager: jQuery("#divOptionTable"),
                rowNum: -1,
                scroll: 0,
                height: $(window).innerHeight() - 450,
                width: '100%',
                viewrecords: true,
                caption: "---caption---",
                emptyrecords: "No records",
                jsonReader: {
                    root: "rows",
                    page: "page",
                    total: "total",
                    records: "records",
                    repeatitems: false
                },
                autowidth: true,
                loadonce: false,
                gridview: true,
                multiselect: false,
                onSelectRow: function (id, status, e) {},
                beforeProcessing: function (data, status, xhr) {},
                ajaxGridOptions: { cache: false },
                gridComplete: function () { },
                ondblClickRow: function () { }
            });
```

By shrink this is what is mean:

[image: JQGrid Shrink View]

Comment: Have you tried autowidth: false ?

Comment: Yes I have also tried it. It just removes the horizontal scrollbar from the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#tblSurveyOption").jqGrid('setGridWidth',  $(window).innerWidth());
```

I don't know there is a bug may be. I used this function at the end of JQGrid function and this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just a random guess (since it could be so many things) but that `$(window).innerHeight` might be the issue.  If the grid generates on page layout, without any content, it might give you a different results depending on your initial page content and on the state of the element.  According to the documentation you should use `clientHeight` instead.  Along with that the Jquery documentation also mentions that using `innerHeight` on an invisible element might give incorrect results.

However overall that's not really the way to do it.

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

...

.parent {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

...

.grid {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  // height: calc(100vh - 450px);
}
```

Remove all the jquery height and width stuff from that element if possible and replace it with flex (if you're able).

Comment: Hey, I read the doc it says that they'll change it from next upgrade. I tried to add hardcoded width like ```100%``` or ```700px``` but the issue still persist

Comment: can you suggest how can i use ```flex``` in my grid ```height```

Comment: As I have shown in the answer, using ````flex: 1 1 auto```` on a child where a parent has ````display: flex```` will make that child fill the entire container.  No need to do any widths or heights.

Comment: ```<div class="row table-responsive">
<div class="col-md-12 flex">
<div class="GridDiv" style="flex: 1 1 auto;">                                                         <table id="tblSurveyOption"></table>
<div id="divSurveyOption"></div>
</div>
</div>
 </div>
```  I have made these changes in my cshtml file and removed width attribute from my JqGrid but the issue still persist.